# Include two element tags in the same selector

Tags: css, less

I have this selector to apply styling to an img tag, if contained in its parent, that does not have an "hidden" class

```
&:has(img:not(.hidden))
```

I want to do the exact same for the video tags within the same parent, so I was thinking something like this

```
&:has(img:not(.hidden), video:not(.hidden))
```

but it doesn't work, webpack fails to compile. Is there a way to put both elements in the same selector?

This is the error thrown by webpack

```
    ERROR in ./src/css/variables-light.less (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--4-2!./src/css/variables-light.less)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):



                    &:has(img:not(.hidden), video:not(.hidden)) {
                                        ^
Missing closing ')
```

Comment: "&:has(img:not(.hidden)), &has(video:not(.hidden))" does not work either?

Comment: yes, this works, but I don't understand why my solution doesn't

Comment: Written as ordinary CSS it seems to be OK so maybe a bug in less/webpack?

Comment: Could you include the error that webpack throws?

Comment: I updated with the error

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code...

```css
div:has(img:not(.hidden), video:not(.hidden)){
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/000/fff" alt=""class="hidden">
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/000/fff" alt="">
</div>

<div>
  <video width="320" height="240" controls class="hidden">
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>

<div>
  <video width="320" height="240" controls class="">
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using less compiled by webpack and that doesn't work...

Comment: webpack must have a problem then